# Migration to Spring Security 6.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have this configuration but don't know how to migrate that to Spring Security 6.1.

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

http.oauth2Login()
  .and()
  .logout(c -> c.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
```

I don't get error messages but the methods are deprecated and I want to know how this has to be done now.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please be a bit more specific in your question, the problems you are facing and what error messages you are receiving and update your question.

Comment: My question is how this must look with Spring Security 6.1

Comment: please post what the current error messages you are getting with the above code, because we cant just randomly guess

Comment: I don't get error messages but the methods are deprecated and I want to know how this has to be done now

Comment: I believe it is the `and` that is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum for the info, then this is what he needs to read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html

Comment: I already know that documentation. But all method calls in the code above are deprecated

Comment: That is odd, as the lambda style is now the preferred one (if I read correctly) there is also no notion of deprecated methods on the `LogoutSpec` only the `and()` and the `oauth2Login()` it. I think the latter 2 are the culprits, try `oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).logout( c -> c.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"));`. The deprecations in [the javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html) are informative.

Comment: Thanks @m.deinum what I don't understand is how to transform the first line when there is no configuration

Comment: See my answer, there is (implicit) configuration, and the `jwt()` is actually a customization to the `OAuth2ResourceServerSpec`. Next to that the `jwt()` also allows for customizations and in itself is deprecated as well (to make matters more confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the little there is in the [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html) and the information in [the Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.html) I suspect that the non usage of the `Customizer` for your other configurations and the `and()` are the problem here.

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer( (c) -> c.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
http.logout( (c) -> c.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler).logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
```

Based on the information I got from the Javadoc the above should work and use non deprecated methods. I'm not sure if this is more readable or not.

Comment: `.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)` also works

Comment: @Toerktumlare Really? jwt() is deprecated

Comment: Ah thats new for 6.1 the correct should be `.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(withDefaults()))`

Comment: Which is what I've written above, as I noticed from the docs that all of that was deprecated (not sure if this is more readable though.